# h:selectBooleanCheckbox is not passing the result to a Map

Tags: jsf, cdi

I want to pass check boxes to a backing CDI-Bean. The **postTest.values** are just a List of Longs.

```
<h:form>
    <h:dataTable value="#{postTest.values}" var="val">
        <h:column>
            <h:outputLabel value="#{val}"/>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{postTest.checked[val]}"/>
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
    <h:commandButton action="#{postTest.process}"/>
</h:form>
```

The action method should print out the checked values. But it is just empty.

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class PostTest {

    List<Long> values;
    Map<Long, Boolean> checked;

    ... 
    public String process() {
        logger.info(this.toString() + "Processing");
        for (Long l : checked.keySet()) {
            logger.info(this.toString() + "\t" + l + ". checked: " + checked.get(l));
        }

        return "index2";
    }
    ...
}
```

When I add logging to the **getChecked()** method, I can see, that it is just retrieved once per column and its content isn't changed at all.

The problem seem to be related to the point that the **postTest.values** is not initialized when the **form** passes the values. Because if I initialize the **postTest.values** in the constructor (or a  @PostConstruct) the checked items are passed correctly.

Why do I need to initialize the **postTest.values** at all after the POST request is executed?

Is there a way to prevent that?

Or do I have another option? E.g. make sure that the **postTest.values** are initialized properly not using the constructor nor the @PostConstruct, cause I want to pass values to it before initialization (I tried listeners, but they don't seem to solve that).

Thanks!

Tim

Comment: I suspect your problem is that the scope is two short. Request scopes counts only for page rendering - first time you access the page. On form submit (postback) a new bean is created and the values needs to be reinitialized. Try increasing the scope to something bigger - like Session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use Myfaces CODI `@ViewAccessScoped` annotation if you don't want to play with `@ConversationScoped` and the `start()` and `end()` methods. it is a CDI extension that is kind of equivalent to `@ViewScoped` of JSF managed bean. I did not check the implementation of this annotation but I see many developers tell that it is even better than `@ViewScoped` annotation.

Just download Myfaces CODI and drop it in your classpath and use the annotation.

Comment: MyFaces CODI allows to use both `@ViewAccessScoped` and `@ViewScoped` for your CDI beans. The difference is mentioned in the WIKI.